# Issues with sharing a list entry with an external user

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, external-users

I have a list on SharePoint Online. When I create a new list entry, I share it with an external user (who doesn't exist on my tenant) to edit it further.

I am facing two issues:

1. When I send a link, the user is asked to create an account and when they do so, they get an error that the user could not be found in the my SharePoint directory. it does look logical because SharePoint doesn't know to which email address I have sent the link to. But is there a way for this solution to work by doing additional steps before/after sending the link?
2. When I share the list entry using the built-in 'Share' button, the user is asked to create an account, but at the end of it they get a message that they don't have permission to access the item and they have to 'request access'. Once they do, they have to wait until I log on and approve their request. My question here is - why are they required to ask for access, in spite that I have shared the item with them?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not feasible to share a list using an anonymous guest link. We can only share a document, folder or a site to external users.

To make external users access list, share the site with them and make them be an authenticated external user and then invite the external users to access the list.

More information check in the article: [Manage external sharing for your SharePoint Online environment](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85#__turn_external_sharing)

Comment: thanks. Apologies if there is a duplication with my original question in what follows. If I share a link with a specific external email id, and that user then goes on to create a Microsoft account with the same id, they get a message that they don't have permission. They need to ask for access. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Firstly, go to SharePoint Admin Center->sharing, make sure you have select “Allow sharing to authenticated external users and using anonymous access links” option under sharing outside your organization section. Then, open the site link firstly in the email and sign in with the account, check if the issue exists.